# xarray: how to get the slice of netcdf file containing variable which have different dimensions & coordinates?

Tags: python, slice, netcdf, python-xarray

I got a netcdf file `PREP.nc` and wants to take a slice of it.

################# INFO ABOUT THE NC FILE ###################

Here is an overlook at the dataset:

```
import xarray as xr
import bumpy as np

dataset = xr.open_dataset(file)
print(dataset)
lat_cord = np.asarray([dataset['LATMIN'].data+i*0.25 + 0.125 for i in range(dataset['NLAT'].data)])
lon_cord = np.asarray([dataset['LONMIN'].data+i*0.25 + 0.125 for i in range(dataset['NLON'].data)])

dataset1 = dataset.assign_coords(lat=lat_cord,lon=lon_cord)
print(dataset1)
```

it prints:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (lat: 15, lon: 21, Number_of_Patches: 12)
Dimensions without coordinates: lat, lon, Number_of_Patches
Data variables: (12/172)
    VERSION       int32 ...
    STORAGETYPE   |S40 ...
           ...
    FRAC_SEA      (lat, lon) float64 ...
```

and

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (lat: 15, lon: 21, Number_of_Patches: 12)
Coordinates:
  * lat           (lat) float64 43.38 43.62 43.88 44.12 ... 46.38 46.62 46.88
  * lon           (lon) float64 -1.625 -1.375 -1.125 ... 2.875 3.125 3.375
Dimensions without coordinates: Number_of_Patches
Data variables: (12/172)
    VERSION       int32 ...
    STORAGETYPE   |S40 ...
    SPLIT_PATCH   |S1 ...
           ...
    FMU_ISBA      (lat, lon) float64 ...
    FMV_ISBA      (lat, lon) float64 ...
    FRAC_SEA      (lat, lon) float64 0.2517 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

There are too many variables. Basically it contains variables of 3 forms: 1) variable of 1*1 dimension; 2) variables of 2 dims `(lat, lon)`; 3) variables of 3 dims `(Number_of_Patches, lat, lon)`. For example, `dataset1['LONMAX']` does not have dimensions or coords, or it has a dimension of 1.

```
dataset1['LONMAX']
Out[149]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'LONMAX' ()>
array(3.5)
Attributes:
    long_name:  LONMAX
    comment:
```

Then some variables are of 2 dimension/coords `(lat, lon)` for example `dataset1['REG_LON']`:

```
dataset1['REG_LON']
Out[151]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'REG_LON' (lat: 15, lon: 21)>
array([[-1.625, -1.375, -1.125, ...,  2.875,  3.125,  3.375],
       ...,
       [-1.625, -1.375, -1.125, ...,  2.875,  3.125,  3.375]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 43.38 43.62 43.88 44.12 ... 46.12 46.38 46.62 46.88
  * lon      (lon) float64 -1.625 -1.375 -1.125 -0.875 ... 2.875 3.125 3.375
Attributes:
    long_name:  REG_LON
    comment:
```

Some have 3 dimensions but 2 coords, `dataset1['WG2']`:

```
dataset1['WG2']
Out[154]: 
<xarray.DataArray 'WG2' (Number_of_Patches: 12, lat: 15, lon: 21)>
array([[[0.317975, 0.29409 , ..., 0.330423, 0.331901],
        [0.278849, 0.270141, ..., 0.306171, 0.334301],
        ...,
        [     nan, 0.283817, ...,      nan, 0.160762],
        [     nan,      nan, ..., 0.152734, 0.177552]]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 43.38 43.62 43.88 44.12 ... 46.12 46.38 46.62 46.88
  * lon      (lon) float64 -1.625 -1.375 -1.125 -0.875 ... 2.875 3.125 3.375
Dimensions without coordinates: Number_of_Patches
Attributes:
    long_name:  WG2
    comment:    X_Y_WG2 (m3/m3)
```

################### WHAT I WANT TO DO ###################

Now I want to take the slice, and take the data/array of `lat = 43.875, lon = 0.375`out of the `PREP.nc`. For variable of 1 dimension like `dataset1['LONMAX']`, it remains same as the original nc file. For variable of 2 dims like `dataset1['REG_LON']`, I need to take the slice of `lat = 43.875, lon = 0.375` like `dataset1['REG_LON'].data[2,8]`. For variable of 3 dims, I also need to take the slice on lat&lon like `dataset1['LONMAX'].data[:,2,8]` (suppose the 2 and 8 are the index of ``lat = 43.875, lon = 0.375```).

################### ISSUE ######################

How can I do that? I tried:

```
dataset2 = dataset1.sel(indexer, "nearest")
```

`dataset2` automatically finds the values on `lat = 43.375, lon = 3.375` which is the first lat and last lon of the original matrix. If I run `dataset2 = dataset1.sel(indexer)`, I got an error message of `KeyError: "not all values found in index 'lat'"`. So I have to fill in the value of `dataset2` one by one by following codes:

```
if len(dataset2[key].dims) == 2:
    dataset2[key] = xr.DataArray(dataset1[key][:,2,8],\
                                  coords={'lat': lat_cord_roi,
                                                'lon': lon_cord_roi},\
                                        dims=['lat', 'lon'],\
                                        attrs=dataset1[key].attrs)
if Len(dataset2[key].dims) == 3:
    dataset2[key] = xr.DataArray(dataset1[key][:,2,8],\
                                        dims=['Number_of_Patches','lat', 'lon'],\
                                        attrs=dataset1[key].attrs)
```

But I am wondering is there any efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: This question has a lot of detail that seems irrelevant to what you are trying to do. Can you simplify it? A minimal reproducible example would also help

Comment: Hi @RobertWilson, I think those details of ```PREP.nc``` helps to solve the problem...

Comment: Hi @RobertWilson, I just tried to simplify it by deleting the print info of dataset and dataset2

Comment: I rolled back the edit - I agree with Robert that this question would benefit from simplifying the example, but just dropping the critical dataset information doesn't help clarify :)

Comment: Ah, thanks @MichaelDelgado, but how can I simplify it?

Comment: Thanks for asking, appreciate you walking through this with us! I feel like we're getting a snapshot of how you're trying to deal with the issue, but I don't have a clear sense of what the issue is. It would be really helpful if you could take a step back, show us a clear example of the problem you're dealing with, and explain fully what you want to do. Make sure to fully describe your goal. "There are too many variables" is a tough one for us to help with - isn't the number of variables just what is contained in the original netCDF? why do you expect there to be fewer variables?

Comment: it may be that there are too many problems to tackle in just one question. That's ok - start with a simple example you're trying to figure out, and we'll work through that one. then you can always ask another question!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado! I just add some basic titles to make it clear 1) the background, i.e. the information of the nc file; 2) what I want to do; 3) issue I met. Btw, "There are too many variables", yes, that's the fact. So I classified them as 3 kinds of variables, a) var of 1 dim; b) var of 2 dims; c) var of 3 dims. And 3 examples are given, respectively. And I don't "expect there to be fewer variables", I just want to take a slice of the netCDF file, i.e take the slice of all variables.

Comment: Why don’t you want to use method ='nearest'?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, as I said in the problem description, I want the value of ```lat = 43.875, lon = 0.375```, but "dataset2 automatically finds the values on lat = 43.375, lon = 3.375 which is the first lat and last lon of the original matrix."